# smooth scrolling for scrollview

Tags: android

I am using a ScrollView to view a file. The problem is that when I scroll, its pretty sticky and not very smooth. I found code for an alert dialog box that is really smooth. Is there any way to make the scrolling on the ScrollView like the alert dialog? How?

Here is an example of the scrollview implementation:

public void buttonLoad(View view) {

```
    File file = new File(path + "/savedFile.txt");
    String [] loadText = Load(file);

    String finalString = "";

    for(int i = 0; i<loadText.length; i++)
    {
        finalString += loadText[i] + System.getProperty("line.separator");
    }

    //textView.setText(finalString);
    //textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

    textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    textView.setText(finalString);

    /*String title = "title";
    String Message = finalString;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(Message);
    builder.show();*/
}
```

Comment: What dialog? Where is your example?

Comment: @cricket_007 This is my first query. I tried to post some code but it seems too long. can you help me out?

Comment: Try to create a [mcve] of your code, and you can link to the example dialog. [edit] accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Use RecyclerView. This scroll view is faster than normal.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerSelectGame"
    >
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html